# Can we set display layout with wkhtmltopdf.exe for pdf

Tags: .net, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf.exe for generating PDF files and its working fine. Now i have requirement to set Display Layout (Single Page view, Two Page View) to open in adobe reader. I am unable to find it in the documentation. 
I wan to be sure that either it's not possible or do we have any setting for the same.

Please advise.

Comment: The best place to ask for this is in the Github issue tracker at https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with wkhtmltopdf alone. This tool will only convert your HTML to a standard PDF.

What you are looking for is an additional tool, which sets the display preferences and you would then run this AFTER you have created the PDF. For example you could use the [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.020/lib/PDF/API2.pm) Perl package (which is free).

Controls viewing preferences for the PDF.

Page Mode Options:

```
-fullscreen

    Full-screen mode, with no menu bar, window controls, or any other window visible.
-thumbs

    Thumbnail images visible.
-outlines

    Document outline visible.


Page Layout Options:

-singlepage

    Display one page at a time.
-onecolumn

    Display the pages in one column.
-twocolumnleft

    Display the pages in two columns, with oddnumbered pages on the left.
-twocolumnright

    Display the pages in two columns, with oddnumbered pages on the right.
```

This should enable you to accomplish your goal.

Comment: how could i use this with asp.net or mvc 4 application?

Comment: you can incorporate the above in a script and call that script from any other application, such as an asp.net one or whatever other language you want

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible as it will require a change in the upstream QT. Use another tool which can add this setting (if it is possible) after the PDF has been generated.